# Make scroll area expand horizontally to fit contents

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt, scrollview

I want to make this **dialog expand horizontally to show all images**. I don't want it to expand vertically, as there will be a scrollbar. The `sizePolicy` stuff that is commented out doesn't help. The images are just four pictures that when side-by-side, are wider than the window.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Images(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, pics, size, imagesPerRow=6, imagePopup=True, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        #sp = QtGui.QSizePolicy()
        #sp.setHorizontalPolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        #self.setSizePolicy(sp)
        #self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sp)
        #self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sp)

        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        self.gLayoutScroll = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        row = col = 0
        for pic in pics:
            thumb = QtGui.QLabel()
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(pic)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(size, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            thumb.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.gLayoutScroll.addWidget(thumb, row, col)

            col +=1
            if col % imagesPerRow == 0:
                row += 1
                col = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myDialog')

    main = Images(['one.png','two.png','three.png','four.png'], size=QtCore.QSize(192,192))
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just set the **minimum width** of the scroll area to the width of the content. That way the scroll area will initially display the full horizontal width of the content widget.

Here is my example (PySide, Python 3):

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Images(QtGui.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, images):
        super().__init__()

        self.content = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.content)
        self.layout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        col = 0
        for image in images:
            thumb = QtGui.QLabel()
            thumb.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(image))
            self.layout.addWidget(thumb, 0, col)
            col += 1

        self.setWidget(self.content)
        self.setMinimumWidth(self.content.sizeHint().width())
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

window = QtGui.QWidget()
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(window)
scroll_area = Images(['test.png','test.png','test.png','test.png'])
layout.addWidget(scroll_area)
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

where is set the minimum width of the scroll bar to the preferred width of the content after adding the images. I also turn the horizontal scroll bar off because then it is not really needed.

The result is a window that is large enough horizontally but not necessarily in the vertical (resized manually).

[image: expanded scroll area]

Two comments:

- If the content changes width you have to do it again.
- The vertical scrollbar will be inside (overlapping) with the content widget. If you do not want that add the width of the vertical scrollbar to the minimum width of the scroll area.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! To account for the scrollbar width, I used (vars from my example):             self.scrollArea.setMinimumWidth(self.gLayoutScroll.sizeHint().width() + self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width() )

Comment: @ChristopherBrown I'm glad it worked also for you. If you like my answer you can also additionally upvote it (if you like).